# Constant expression required in switch statements

Tags: java, switch-statement, factory-method

have this `enum` file containing some information:

```
public enum Constants {
    AGED_BRIE("Aged Brie");

    private final String label;

    Constants(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

this `Item` class:

```
public class Item {
    public String name;

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and this factory method:

```
public class Factory {

    public void try(Item item) {
        String brie = Constants.AGED_BRIE.getLabel(); // contains "Aged Brie"
        switch (item.name) {
            case brie -> System.out.println("Hello World"); // Constant expression required
            // other cases ...
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get:

> Constant expression required

and IntelliJ highlights `case label` statement.

- What am I missing?

Comment: The evaluation of the method call `getLabel()` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: @khelwood Any other ways to achieve my purpose?

Comment: You could just use an if-else if construct to handle dynamic cases that aren't compile time constant.

Comment: Do not use public variables in your classes make them private and access it by getter

Comment: @Jens Item class is a read-only file.

Comment: What so you means with `read-only` file? If I whrit e`item.name="x"` I will change the value of the property

Comment: @Jens Cannot alter it.

Comment: Introduce a method `getByLabel` into your enum and use it in the switch statement

Comment: @Jens What's the purpose of that method in my context?

Comment: To get the enum for the label. See the answer of @ElliottFrisch. that's what i thought about

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a method named `try`. You need your case(s) to expand to constants. You shouldn't make fields public. But let's start by making `Constants` into `Cheese`. Like,

```
public enum Cheese {
    CHEDDAR("Cheddar"), AGED_BRIE("Aged Brie");

    private final String label;

    Cheese(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Now in `Item`, instead of `String`(s) we want to use the `enum` type so you have something to match on in constant expressions later. Not changing `Constants` would have made this confusing. Like,

```
public class Item {
    private Cheese cheese;

    public Item(Cheese cheese) {
        this.cheese = cheese;
    }

    public Cheese getCheese() {
        return cheese;
    }
}
```

Now, we can actually use that for our `case`(s). It's a `Factory`. We can `make` things. Like,

```
public void make(Item item) {
    switch (item.getCheese()) {
    case AGED_BRIE -> System.out.println("Aged Brie");
    case CHEDDAR -> System.out.println("Cheddar");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough general. Item should not be modified, moreover.

Comment: @Anna This code works. Examine how it differs from your current approach and do the needful.

Comment: You are modifying Item file. It should not be modified at all.

Comment: @Anna *You are modifying Item file. It should not be modified at all.* Sadly then I think this is a case of our old friend [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/243725). Instead of describing your attempted solution, please elaborate on the actual problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: @Anna, are you saying that the Item class is universally used or from old code, it is not OK if one change it?